# grunt-contrib-jade not outputting, no task error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, pug

Here is the part of my Gruntfile.js that refers to jade:

```
jade: {
  html: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: "source/jade/",
        src: "[*.jade]",
        dest: "build/",
        ext: ".html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My .jade files are in source/jade/file.jade, I want .html files to all be outputted in build/file.html

When I `grunt jade`, it says that the task has been completed with no errors, yet from what I can tell, not a single file in my project has been changed. Any help?

Comment: Have you checked it's documentation? Shouldn't the src attribute be an array? `src: ['*.jade']`?

Comment: What a stupid error on my part. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @KevinLewis, What was the issue ???

Comment: Quotes on the inside of the array - `src: ["*.jade"]`